# get codeigniter session data in external file

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

i have one php file `image.php` which generate images thumb in my codeigniter application.

this php file is in public_html directory.

now i only want to give access to this file to logged in users, so i want to get session variable in my `image.php` file and see if user is logged in or not.

i am trying this by using this code

```
ob_start();
include(‘index.php’);
ob_end_clean();
$CI =& get_instance();

if(!empty($CI->session->userdata('user_id'))) {

}
```

but i am getting error and it's not working.

as i write above `image.php` is in `public_html` with `index.php` in same folder.

Thanks for your help

Comment: `image.php` should place inside project folder

Comment: dear Abdullah, this is not possible cause i am calling this image.php from every view to load images.

Comment: You should add the exact error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codeigniter passes all of it's file via index.php, so nothing from the CI library is loaded. You need to create the file as a part of helpers or a library for CI to be able to use the code.

Check this link:

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Try this:

```
$filename="/path/to/file.jpg"; //<-- specify the image  file
if(file_exists($filename)){ 
  header('Content-Length: '.filesize($filename)); //<-- sends filesize header
  header('Content-Type: image/jpg'); //<-- send mime-type header
  header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$filename.'";'); //<-- sends filename header
  readfile($filename); //<--reads and outputs the file onto the output buffer
  die(); //<--cleanup
  exit; //and exit
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help but how to get image output from help like `header("Content-type: image/jpeg");echo file_get_contents($imgpath);' i tries but its not working from helper

Comment: thanks so much but its not working, only showing blank page.  i have copy exactly your code but its not working but when i echo the `$filename` its showing me full path of file like this `http://localhost/mysite/uploads/1.jpg` but image is not showing...

Comment: Are you sure the server has permission for that file?

Comment: yes cause when i put the url which is same as `$filename` in browser , i can see the image...